# emu8086 multiple org directives

Tags: assembly

emu8086 won't place code at my second org directive.  If this a quirk with emu8086 or is my assembly wrong.  Link is to a screen shot of emu8086 with code in question.

Thank you.

http://postimg.org/image/kcgu5ndw5/

```
#make_bin#

#LOAD_SEGMENT=0F000h#
#LOAD_OFFSET=0000h#

#CS=0F000h#
#IP=00000h#

#DS=04567h#
#ES=00000h#

#SS=04567h#
#SP=01110h#

#AX=0000h#
#BX=0000h#
#CX=0000h#
#DX=0000h#
#SI=0000h#
#DI=0000h#
#BP=0000h#

org 0f000h

mov ax,01211h   ;0150-[11,12,13,ab,cb,22,34,16,33]
mov [0150h],ax

mov ax,013ABh
mov [0152h],ax

mov ax,022CBh
mov [0154h],ax

mov ax,01634h
mov [0156h],ax


mov al,33h
mov [0158h],al              

jmp 0f100h 


org 0f100h

mov ax, 0abh    
add ax, 0abh    ;156h
pop bx          ;??
mov bx, ax      ;156h
mov cx, [bx]    ;1634h
push cx         ;
jmp cx          ;??
mov al, 10h     ;execution not determined   



HLT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assembler doesn't load the code.  You have to do that.  "org" tells the assembler where you are going to load the code.  If you have multiple org directives, you are telling the assembler you are going to load it in multiple pieces.  I think what you want instead of the second org is to add padding something like:

```
rb  0f100h - $
```

Comment: Thank you.  I forgot that org just helps the assembly make address calculations and doesn't move code.  Moving code is done by padding or physical location of memory banks.

Comment: The line I needed:
`label_1 db (0100h - (label_1 - start)) DUP (0FFh)`