# How the datas are loaded to wanted memory fields as byte?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086

We can write `ASSIGN DB 10, 20, 30, 40, 50` command in emu8086 but it loads these bytes to random memory fields.

How can I load these bytes to the memory field I wanted? For example, I want to define these bytes beginning from A40EH.

Comment: During runtime, or in the executable itself? During runtime you simply copy those bytes at target address (for example with `rep movsb` instruction). In the executable itself it may be more tricky, check how your linker script looks, where in source you have to position those data, so they will "land" on desired address. This is somewhat relevant (mentioning `org` directive, and how to pad unused space): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17798769/emu8086-multiple-org-directives  ... how to check linker script of emu8086 linker = I have no idea, I don't even know what linker it does use.

Comment: BTW, you better should know, what you are doing, and picked that target address with consideration, so you know what you are overwriting and why. Under normal circumstances this request doesn't make sense, so if you are not sure what you are doing, then you are doing very likely something wrong.

Comment: Are you talking about segment A40EH or offset A40EH?

Comment: @Jose Manuel Abarca Rodríguez Not segment, it is offset

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Memory addresses contain two parts : segment and offset. The segment is assigned by the operating system, the offset is determined by the data itself. The programmer can control the offset. In your case, if you want some data in a specific position you can fill your data segment with lots of bytes until you get the desired position, example :

```
.model large
.stack 100h
.data
            ▼
filler db 0A40Eh dup(?)               ;◄■■ BYTES 0 TO 0A40DH.
ASSIGN DB 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 'END$'  ;◄■■ BYTES START AT 0A40EH.

.code
  mov ax, @data
  mov ds, ax

  mov ah, 9
  lea dx, ASSIGN
  int 21h             ;◄■■ DISPLAY ASSIGN TO CHECK IF WORKS.

  mov ah, 0
  int 16h             ;◄■■ WAIT FOR A KEY PRESS.

  mov ax, 4c00h
  int 21h
```